# Why this issue occures when I tried to run automation test for chrome, I ensure from the compitability versions between Chrome and Chrome Driver

Tags: google-chrome, driver

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-E1SNOS9', ip: '192.168.1.16'
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:52)
at automationFramework.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '21.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
... 7 more

I tried to test chrome by using Chrome Driver but give this issue.